# How can database table column data load for the Bunifu Framework BunifuDropdown?

Tags: c#, winforms, bunifu

I have a problem. MS SQL database table column data how can load BunifuDropdown. The normal C# code does not work. Please help

Comment: What is `BunifuDropdown`? What is the "normal C# code"? What code do you have here that isn't working? Is this a question for the support forum of "Bunifu Framework"?

Comment: Normal windows form ComboBox introduces in "Bunifu Framework " using "BunifuDropdown".

Comment: Like this code normally I use for added new items. But it's not support Bunifu Framework. cbxDSRname.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["UserName"]);

Comment: based on the usage of the [tag:bunifu] tag, I think this is a fairly niche topic; most people are unlikely to have used this framework - you *may* do better looking for support options with whoever provides Bunifu

Comment: I hate now this framework. But now I developed my project part of 80% using this framework. So I can't be stoping this. What u think about like frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bunifudropdown.AddItem("");`

Comment: thanks a lot. "Items" and "Add" not here separate keywords.

Answer (score 1):

we just need to convert the Normal way to add value in Sql (like text Box)  to add from the dropdown and we do it by Choose the value from the Array!! (Because the Values in Drop Down is Stored in Array), So we Need to make like Pointer for Values And All of that Inside(Selected Value).

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level",bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.